# Should I exclude all 'dev/' or only 'dev/pts/' during full server tar backup?

Tags: backup, filesystems, tar

I'm curious why in all backup tutorials I found tar command excludes among others `/dev/pts`
and not all of `/dev/`
Why would I want to backup anything under dev?

Comment: back in the day when you still had to create device entries manually with `mknod` maybe, with udev I see no particular reason, no.

Answer (score 6):

There is generally no need to backup anything under dev, since it's mostly generated upon boot by udev. I did a lot of OS migrations by simply rsyncing everything except stuff like proc, dev, sys etc.

Just make sure when you setup your backups, ALWAYS test a recovery, to see if everything is functioning properly.

Comment: Can I use some tar option to make it check file after compression?

Comment: You mean to check the integrity of backed up files? There's probably more than one way to do it, but I was actually referring to something else. Since you're doing full server backups, I suggest you try to restore the server backup on a different machine, to make sure it actually boots, and that everything is OK.

Comment: Good suggestion but somehow missing the point because this backup will (i hope not) be restored on the same machine it's being created.
So to test it in "battle conditions" I would need to wreck my production server...

Comment: Of course you wouldn't test it on your actual production machine, but try to restore it on a similar machine, or a VM. Make sure you run the grub installation if restoring to new hard drives. :)

Comment: Note that *udev* is Linux specific. On other unixoid systems with a static `/dev`, it is indeed advisable to include it in the backup, and only exclude `/dev/pts`, which is dynamically managed even there.